# Ionic iOS8 form field focus causes page to scroll incorrectly

Tags: javascript, ios8, keyboard, ionic-framework

Pls see video for example (sorry about the dark box overlay). Video is taken from an iPhone emulator (via Browserstack)

When I click into a form field, and that field is lower than the center of the screen, the whole page jumps up and then scrolls down quickly - not far enough though - so that you cannot see the form field behind the keyboard. Additionally the page was zooming in (again the form field would dissapear behind the keyboard) - and then NOT zooming back out. For the time being I have disabled zooming or scaling in the meta viewport tag

I have seen other posts where they recommend the keyboard plugin for cordova. I am not using Cordova. This happens in iOS 8 and Windows, not andriod

This view is directly in safari, however the finished product will be in an application wrapper

Is there anyway to fix this when NOT using Cordova?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXhwCewI76I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, you can see some details in the below links:

- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2911
- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2061

**Workaround** will be to use the Keyboard plugin, and disable the Scroll using the method `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` to disable native scrolling.

Details of the plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard).